# Mobile Application Security Testing Approach

Tags: mobile-application

Can anybody explain me, what is the approach for Mobile App Security testing? In addition

looking for a sample reporting template.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile applications are two types.

1. Browser based apps
2. Hybrid/Native apps.

Depending upon the application, you are testing. The testing approach slightly changes. Usually, most will follow OWASP guidelines for mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

First, a thorough threat modeling of the app you have designed must be done. Threat modeling will give you a sense of the possible vulnerabilities. 
Example: Mobile app is letting an other APP to interact with you app/app data. In such cases, you should have accessed
1. How should other app must be authenticated with you?
2. What are the privileges given and can access what kind of data?
3. Should the other app be able to use encryption key of your own app? - Must be not.

etc.... Hence, I insist you do a clean thread modeling of the app and fine out
1. All interfaces via which app exchanges data. 
2. Disk store, what kind of transactions have access to store and what is it intended to? - Authorization
3. Encrypt all the critical data in a store, use SALT if app is exchanging more data very often.
4. Code execution path. No code be in app which do not have a purpose to do.
5. Incoming data sanitation.

etc...